# Is it a bad idea to put real papers on the arXiv during April Fool's Day?

Tags: arxiv

There're lots of spoof papers on the arXiv every April Fool's day. I'm wondering if it's a bad idea to upload a real paper on April 1, in case people dismiss the paper as a joke.

Comment: As an anecdote, Arch Linux [published an official guided installer](https://archlinux.org/news/installation-medium-with-installer/) on April 1st last year. Reactions on r/archlinux were somewhat confused, but the git repo speaks for itself, and it seems well-received now. The maintainers were pretty cheeky when they published it on April 1st, but why not? Just because some jokers may or may not submit some jokes, this shouldn't preclude legit papers from being submitted on whatever date their authors seem fit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have also seen serious papers posted on arxiv on April Fool's Day. If anything, I have found the joke papers to be rarer than the real ones. It's usually easy to tell from the title and abstract if the paper is a joke or not. (If it isn't clear, you might want to rewrite your title and abstract :)). So I don't think it would matter. But, in most cases, I would think delaying submission by one day would not be a major issue, if you were concerned.

Comment: If you upload your paper on April 1, it will appear in the arXiv a few days later.

Comment: @markvs Do you mean this year, because April 1 is on a Friday? (a) I'm not trying to write an answer tied to 2022, and (b) the point stands whether it is one day or one weekend.

Comment: Any year. But a paper submitted on Friday will certainly appear after Monday. In general if a paper is submitted on day X, it will appear on day X+i, i>0..

Comment: @markvs But that is only relevant in years where April Fool's is on a Friday or Saturday. If you want to handle all of the edge cases explicitly, you are free to write an answer.

Comment: As I said - any year.

Comment: @markvs (a) Your comment "If you upload your paper on April 1, it will appear in the arXiv a few days later" is incorrect in general -- it's only true if April 1 is on a Friday or Saturday, or the person missed the submission deadline. (b) If you read what I wrote, I didn't claim in the answer that submitting on April 1 would cause the submission to appear on April 2. What I said was that if you were worried about submitting on a day where your paper would appear on April 1, then just wait to submit 1 day. That strategy would lead to your paper appearing as soon as possible after 4/1.

Comment: I have 57 papers in the arXiv. I know the procedure.

Comment: I don't get what Andrew's objection is on markvs comment? Andrew said: "it's only true if April 1 is on a Friday or Saturday", why? So if April 1 is not on a Friday, uploading the paper on April 1 will be published on the same day? I think it's not the case.

Comment: If you uploaded a paper on April 1, 2022 (Friday) before 14:00 Eastern US time, then April 1 is the date that will be on the arXiv page of the paper. But as mentioned the paper will be announced later.

Comment: Bizarre comments about the number of arxiv postings aside, I think it's good to clarify the various timelines around arxiv submission. However, I also want to be clear that my answer simply says to submit a day later if you don't want the paper to appear on April 1, which does not imply anything about when the paper will appear. As we've discussed, *sometimes* if you submit on April 1, it will appear on April 2, and other times it will appear a few days later, after the weekend.

Comment: +1  April Fool's is a dreadful "holiday".  The best thing we can do is to not take part in deliberately gaslighting people and to go about our business like it doesn't exist.  I, for one, refuse to cede a perfectly useful workday on account of jokers with no sense of consideration and who delight in wasting other peoples' time.